# Why normalize.css doesn't set font-style: italic for <i> and <em> tags?

Tags: html, css

`normalize.css` sets `font-weight: bold;` for `<b>` and `<strong>` tags.

I would expect it to have `font-style: italic;` for `<i>` and `<em>`, however it specifies `font-style: italic;` only for `<dfn>` tag.

https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#l118-l129

```
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: the reason is explained just above, lines 114-116 : https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#l114-116

Comment: If not difficult, please explain how `Address style set to 'bolder' in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.` is related to italics.

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to set the font-style, because the font style is already the same in all browsers. The only things in normalize.css are things that differ across browsers. Firefox has "bolder" for `<b>` while other browsers have "bold". _That_ is what normalize.css does, it irons out those differences.

Comment: Fabrizio, Mr Lister: I think I got your points, thanks!

Comment: @MrLister can you please post an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

`<i>` and `<em>` tags are always italic, whatever browser you're on.

Normalize adjusts:

```
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Because some browsers choose to display `<b>` and `<strong>` with `font-weight: bolder` instead of `font-weight: bold`. As stated in the non-minfied file:

```
/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is an answer already! See @Mr Lister comment

Comment: Ah, but he didn't post it as an answer!

Comment: @sbedulin This answer is good enough... Well, maybe Daniel could have included [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5qnsd3um/) to demonstrate the `<b>` issue.